# Preserve case during visual studio regex find and replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, replace

I'm trying to find and replace strings using the Visual Studio regex find and replace in some code which includes a lot of inline documentation.

> e.g. replace "east" with "north", and "East" with "North".

Since the files contain grammatically correct English right now, I want to be careful not to alter the case of text that may get replaced in the comments.

I know you can turn on the match case, or have one regex for lowercase and one for capitalized words, but I'm wondering if I actually have to do it twice or not (obviously I don't want to).

I've seen other answers for perl and javascript which give language-specfic answers to this question (requiring callbacks), but I'm wondering if it's possible to do just within the visual studio dialog.

Comment: @ndn I kinda figured, but thanks for the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study [*Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), you will see that there are no such an operator that would keep the case of any specified letter matched/captured with a regex.

In some regex flavors, like in Perl and R `(g)sub`, you could turn your captures/matches lower/uppercase with a specific operator, but again, it would be a hardcoded action, not keeping the original case intact.

Thus, the only option you have with regex is to run individual search and replace operations (like `east` --> `north` and `East` --> `North`, maybe with word boundaries around `\beast\b` to match a whole word).

Else, you need to process the text with some custom code written in some full fledged language.

Comment: that's what I figured, but it's a bummer.